# Raspberry Pi 3B+ XRDP Very Slow!

Tags: pi-3b+, raspicam, rdp, xrdp

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and I just installed `xrdp` on it. I wanted to do this so I can do some ROS projects. But just after using RDP to log in to the Pi, I was welcomed with a painfully slow desktop. I have plenty of internet speed/bandwidth. My Picamera that I have attached to the Pi is also very slow and I am getting very low FPS. Is there anything I can do to fix all of this?

Specs:

- Raspberry Pi 3B+
- Picamera with Ribbon
- Proper Cooling(heatsinks, fans)
- Good internet speed(20Mbps Download,
- Raspberry OS with Latest Updates

Comment: how big is your sd card? Maybe you can try one with more space

Comment: It is 32GB and it is not that full.....I think.

Comment: should be fine; are you having the same issue when you login to the pi directly without using xrdp?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try editing /usr/bin/startlxde-pi and set TOTAL_MEM=ge20480. That solved the problem for me.